# How to include vendors in apple pay

Tags: ios, swift, payment, vendor, applepay

I'm using swift and setting up apple pay on an app to pay a business for goods.  I've already setup the apple pay button and functionality and it goes through the process of completing payment but i dont understand how to get the payment to the actual business account.  Where can i learn this step?

Comment: The business needs to have a merchant account with a card acquirer that supports Apple Pay and you configure these details in your app

Comment: If you want to collect the money on the business's behalf and then pay them, then this is outside the scope of Apple Pay

Comment: Where can i find information on how to configure those details in my app? I would like to know how to implement either scenario since i haven't decided yet...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ApplePay_Guide/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014764-CH2-SW1

Comment: Thanks for the link, the only thing i am stuck on is the part where my app knows which merchants will be receiving money.

Comment: That is up to you.  I don't think Apple Pay allows you to remit to multiple merchants.  You need to handle that on your back-end through some other payment system

Comment: I wish I knew where to start.